# Sending raw data in Scapy does not work correctly

Tags: scapy

I use Scapy to create an initial OpenVPN packet and send it to OpenVPN server (acting as a client). OpenVPN part of the packet I'm just reusing from old captured connection, but its irrelevant here.

Thing is, I add a payload of 42bytes but for some reason when I capture packet with Wireshark, I can see 84bytes of OpenVPN stuff. Last half of that is correct payload I sent, but I can't figure out what is the first half. All other layers (Ethernet, IP, UDP) have correct size.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
from scapy.all import *

mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mysocket.connect(('192.168.138.129', 1194))

mystream=StreamSocket(mysocket)

ascapypacket=Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.138.129")/UDP(dport=1194, len=50)/Raw(load="\x38\x81\x38\x14\x62\x1d\x67\x46\x2d\xde\x86\x73\x4d\x2c\xbf\xf1\x51\xb2\xb1\x23\x1b\x61\xe4\x23\x08\xa2\x72\x81\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x01\x50\xff\x26\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")

etherLoad = len(ascapypacket.getlayer(Ether)) # display size
print etherLoad
ipLoad = len(ascapypacket.getlayer(IP)) # display size
print ipLoad
udpLoad = len(ascapypacket.getlayer(UDP)) # display size
print udpLoad
rawLoad = len(ascapypacket.getlayer(Raw)) # display size
print rawLoad

mystream.send(ascapypacket)
```

I made an image. Here you can see green stuff is correct - first part is IP and UDP layers, and 2nd green part is my OpenVPN payload, but I don't understand what is the red part.

[image]

Edit: If I don't send that Raw payload I still get those 42 bytes for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created an ordinary *UDP* datagram socket:

```py
mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

This socket manages the *ethernet*, *IP* & *UDP* layers by itself, with guidance from the user through various auxiliary methods and arguments, such as the `connect` method you've in fact used in your code snippet:

```py
mysocket.connect(('192.168.138.129', 1194))
```

Its various `send` methods, even when encapsulated as part of a *scapy*'s `StreamSocket` object, are expecting to receive as their "data-to-send" argument just the application payload layered above the *UDP* layer.
However, you're passing on to it the entire protocol stack payload, i.e. the *ethernet*, *IP* & *UDP* headers, which is misinterpreted to be part of the payload data that you wish to send to the other side:

```py
ascapypacket=Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.138.129")/UDP(dport=1194, len=50)/Raw(load="\x38\x81\x38\x14\x62\x1d\x67\x46\x2d\xde\x86\x73\x4d\x2c\xbf\xf1\x51\xb2\xb1\x23\x1b\x61\xe4\x23\x08\xa2\x72\x81\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x01\x50\xff\x26\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

Thus, the data you've marked in red is actually the payload data you've yourself set, before it is followed by the *OpenVPN* part:

```py
Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.138.129")/UDP(dport=1194, len=50)
```

The first part marked in green, which you've mistakenly identified as created by yourself, is actually generated by the `socket` object (the kernel, the appropriate driver and the underlying hardware, to be more accurate).

---

Depending on your needs, you should either instantiate your socket as a raw one:

```py
mysocket = socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
```

or set the payload accordingly as just the *OpenVPN* data:

```py
ascapypacket=Raw(load="\x38\x81\x38\x14\x62\x1d\x67\x46\x2d\xde\x86\x73\x4d\x2c\xbf\xf1\x51\xb2\xb1\x23\x1b\x61\xe4\x23\x08\xa2\x72\x81\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x01\x50\xff\x26\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

Comment: You're right! I missed that completely. Thank you for good explanation.